# subarray of bigint[] in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to get n first elements  and n last elements of bigint[] in postgresql

in this link is all about int[] but not bigint[]
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/intarray.html

so, something like this:

```
delchain := subarray(usr.chain, 1, (schain - mchain));
```

gives to me this error:

> ```
> function subarray(bigint[], integer) does not exist
> ```

is it possible to avoid this error?

Comment: You didn't install the `intarray` extension. Run `create extension intarray` as a superuser.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , it didn't help